# How to set Ext.net Loading mask in window/panel control using javascript function?

Tags: javascript, ext.net

```
function showImageFn(imgID,frmPanelPicture) {                                                                                                               
    var myMask = new Ext.LoadMask(Ext.getCmp('frmPanelPicture').el{msg:'Loading'});  //showing error 

    var myMask = new Ext.LoadMask(frmPanelPicture, {msg:"Loading..."}); //showing error                                                                                   
    loadMask.show();
    ShowPicMethod.ShowImage(imgID)
 };
```

Shows JavaScript runtime error:

> 'frmPanelPicture' is undefined

But If I use the following code snippet:

```
Ext.getBody().mask("Loading..."); //it's work fine
```

But it's works on hole body but I do n't want this,I want to give loading mask only the window/panel control not for the hole body/page.Please help me out.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Masking is always apply to body of any element. So we have to find out the body using `Ext.getCmp("frmPanelPicture").getBody()` and then apply masking as below

```
 var myMask = new Ext.LoadMask(Ext.getCmp("frmPanelPicture").getBody(), {msg:"Loading..."});
 myMask.show();
```

try this

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: @abarisone : now is it proper ?

Answer (score 0):

Your trying to find the element called 'frmPanelPicture'.  Unless you are using IDMode=Static your panel the element will not be added to the DOM as  'frmPanelPicture' it will be App.frmPanelPicture.

In chrome press F12 and go to the console, type 'App.' and check out how Ext.NET has structured all your elements.  Your panel is going to be named something like App.frmPanelPicture or App.ctl00_mainContent_frmPanelPicture.

On the other hand, the Ext.NET guys did a great job anticipating where you are going to need a mask.  You can make the mask you want on most directevents.  Besure you've exhausted those native options before scripting your own.

```
<ext:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Height="300" Title="Title" IDMode="Static">
    <Buttons>
        <ext:Button ID="Button1" runat="server">
            <DirectEvents>
                <Click OnEvent="Button1_Click">
                    <EventMask Msg="loading..." CustomTarget="#{Panel1}" Target="CustomTarget">
                    </EventMask>
                </Click>
            </DirectEvents>
        </ext:Button>
    </Buttons>
```